# JQuery .on() live calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a ul list. The

items are appended to the list, when the user click on a button. This part of the script is working fine and the items are appended to the ul list. But I have an issue in the second part. Each button has a value (integer). I sum the values and show the sum in a field. This is also working without errors. However, it works only when li items already are published in the ul. For dynamic li items it does not work. I need an .on() or .live() function for that?

Here are the scripts

```
//append to costs //
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button_grey').click(function() {
    var toAdd = $(this).attr('name');
    var toAdd2 = $(this).attr('value');
    $('.ul-panel').append('<li class="items">' + toAdd + '<div class="float_right">CHF <span class="numbs">' + toAdd2 + '</span> <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></div></i></li>');
  });
  $(document).on('click touchstart', '.items', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});

//calculation addition //
$(document).ready(function() {
function totalList() {
    var subTotal = 0;

    jQuery("#totalsum li").each(function() {
      subTotal += parseFloat(
        jQuery(this).find('span').text()
        .replace('$ ', '')
        .replace(',', ''));

    });
    var subTotal = subTotal.toFixed(2);
    $('.numbercosts').html(subTotal);
  };
  totalList();
});
```

And here you have the html code.

```
<div class="footer_div">
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <ul class="ul-panel" id="totalsum">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="float_left">
        <span class="details"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Details</span>
    </div>
    <div class="float_right costsli">
        <span class="costs">
            geschätzte Kosten
        </span>
        <span class="numbercosts" id="numbercosts"></span><span class="costs"> CHF</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button is for example the follows:

```
<button class="button_grey" value="950" name="Android">
                    <center>
                <i class="fa fa-android fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h4>
                        Android
                    </h4>
                        </center>
            </button>
```

Comment: i din't see any button code there? also function inside `document.ready` is not correct. put it outside

Comment: I added the button where I get the name and value attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes:-

1.Call function `totalList();`inside `$('.button_grey').click(function() {` and  `$(document).on('click touchstart', '.items', function() {`

2.Put function code  outside of `$(document).ready(function(){..})`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.button_grey').click(function() {
    var toAdd = $(this).attr('name');
    var toAdd2 = $(this).attr('value');
    $('.ul-panel').append('<li class="items">' + toAdd + '<div class="float_right">CHF <span class="numbs">' + toAdd2 + '</span> <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></div></i></li>');
    totalList();
  });
  $(document).on('click touchstart', '.items', function() {
    $(this).remove();
    totalList();
  });
});
function totalList() {
 var subTotal = 0;
 jQuery(".numbs").each(function() {
   subTotal += parseFloat(jQuery(this).text());
 });
 var subTotal = subTotal.toFixed(2);
 $('.numbercosts').html(subTotal);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer_div">
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <ul class="ul-panel" id="totalsum">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="float_left">
        <span class="details"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Details</span>
    </div>
    <div class="float_right costsli">
        <span class="costs">
            geschätzte Kosten
        </span>
        <span class="numbercosts" id="numbercosts"></span><span class="costs"> CHF</span>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="button_grey" value="950" name="Android"><center><i class="fa fa-android fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i><h4>Android</h4></center></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

extract the function totalList out of the document ready, then call it where needed..

```
//calculation addition //
function totalList() {
    var subTotal = 0;

    jQuery("#totalsum li").each(function() {
      subTotal += parseFloat(
        jQuery(this).find('span').text()
        .replace('$ ', '')
        .replace(',', ''));

    });
    var subTotal = subTotal.toFixed(2);
    $('.numbercosts').html(subTotal);
  };
//append to costs //
$(document).ready(function() {
  totalList();
  $('.button_grey').click(function() {
    var toAdd = $(this).attr('name');
    var toAdd2 = $(this).attr('value');
    $('.ul-panel').append('<li class="items">' + toAdd + '<div class="float_right">CHF <span class="numbs">' + toAdd2 + '</span> <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></div></i></li>');
  });
  $(document).on('click touchstart', '.items', function() {
    //$(this).remove();
    totalList();//maybe here?
  });
});
```

Comment: you code is correct but this `$(document).ready(function() {totalList();});` is unnecessary.remove it. and add function call in both one. BTW +1 for your effort